# How can I see the Pi HDMI display when I VCN in

Tags: headless

I have a Pi 3B set up with a 3.5" touch display. I want to use a laptop or tablet to VNC in and control the Pi headless.  I have TightVNC running on the Pi and am using RealVNC as the client(Viewer).  The problem is the remote desk top is a second instance rather than showing the same instance as the 3.5" TFT.

Does anybody know a way of having it work as the same desk top?

Also I use a mac and can not cut and past from the mac desk top to the Pi desktop - any ideas why?

THanks

Answer (score 0):

Don't use TightVNC.

Use  RealVNC (included with Raspbian - unless you disabled it by installing TightVNC).

It is unclear if this would work with a TFT screen - this depends on how it was installed.